# Using $resource to POST with a body

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

How do I do a normal `POST` with a payload body with Angular `$resource`. Right now, when I `POST`, it posts to `/api/example?name=JoeSmith&is_whatever=false`, instead of posting with a body.

Let's say I have the following:

```
ENDPOINT: `/api/example`
BODY: {
   "name": "Joe Smith",
   "is_whatever": false
}
```

**API Service**

```
angular.module('example')
   .factory('APIService', ['$resource',

        function($resource) {

           return $resource('/api/example', {}, {
              create: {
                 method: 'POST',
              }
           });          

        }]);
```

**Example usage**

```
    // body i need to POST
    var payload = {
       name: 'Joe Smith',
       is_whatever: false        
    };

    APIService.create(payload).$promise.then(function(res){
        // doesnt work
    });
```

Comment: Does this work: `APIService.create({}, payload).$promise.then(...)`

Comment: first argument should be params or blank {} then the payload
`
APIService.create({}, payload).$promise.then(function(res){
        // doesnt work
    });
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the data parameter to the action method of the resource as follows:

```
angular.module('example', ['ngResource'])

.run(function(APIService) {
   var payload = {
      name: 'Joe Smith',
      is_whatever: false        
   };
   APIService.save({}, payload)
})

.factory('APIService', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/api/example');
});
```